# Supporting between GL versions 3.1 and 4.x

Tags: opengl, cross-platform, preprocessor, glsl

Since I've been studying OpenGL, I've been running into a bit of dilemma: while I have a good video card which supports GL 4.3 (`nVidia GTX 550 ti` model), my laptop is running off of integrated graphics (Intel HD 3000, from an `i5-2410M` to be exact), which runs version 3.1. I have no idea if this card is even capable of supporting OpenGL 3.2.

Either way, if it turns out that a driver update is all that's needed for core i3/i5 processors to support OpenGL 3.2+, I'm still not sure where I should look or what *exactly* I need to pay attention to in order support between 3.x and 4.x.

For example, AFAIK GLSL 1.4 doesn't support a shader which uses the `layout(location=x) in blah blah` feature. But, does GLSL 1.5?

What about preprocessor directives in C/C++ *as well as* GLSL which I can use to distinguish between what features work with what? Or, is it more recommended (in either GLSL's or C/C++'s case) to just write completely separate header/source/shader files which take care of this?

Since I only plan to be supporting 3.x to 4.x, I know this should be simpler than it very well could be.

**Update**

After a recent driver update on my laptop, it turns out that, as Nicol Bolas also stated, there currently is not (and likely won't ever be) any support for 3.2 on Intel 3000 cards. Therefore, to make this question simpler, I'd like to know what shading language features (be it in an answer or an external URL) I can and cannot implement on version 3.1 in comparison to 3.3 and above. Any OpenGL specific C/C++ features/functions which pertain to this would also be appreciated.

My goal is to basically be able to know what I have to do in order to mediate between the project I'm working on (which is currently using a GL 4.0 context) to be compatible with a 3.1 context.

If anything is still unclear I'll update accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: "*I have no idea if this card is even capable of supporting OpenGL 3.2.*" It's *capable* of it. It probably never will, because Intel won't update the drivers for it, but the hardware is capable of it. Indeed, it provides 3.2 support under MacOSX.

Comment: It's a bit unclear as to what exactly you're asking for. The only question I can see here is what version of OpenGL provides explicit vertex attribute index specification.

Comment: @NicolBolas question updated.

Comment: Now it sounds like you're asking us to give you a list of what's in GLSL versions higher than 1.40.

Comment: Is that bad? What about a URL of some sort which can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is check out the latest header at the [OpenGL registry](http://www.opengl.org/registry/#headers) called glcorearb.h. It has a list of every function definition from 1.0 onwards, broken up with defines labeling the respective versions in which they were introduced (and eligible for).

I'm not 100% sure of where to get GLSL information, but they do keep the specifications for older releases, so you may be able to compare the latest to the older ones for that.

Edit: Corrected wrong link.

Check [the spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.20.11.clean.pdf) and [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_Language_%28GLSL%29#Preprocessor_directives) for preprocessor directives and such.

Does this help?

Comment: I think I may be misinterpreting your question. Do you want to discover OpenGL/GLSL support _in code_, or on you own so that you can code appropriately?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misinterpreted what you just said as well: what do you mean by discovering OpenGL/GLSL support in code, versus on my own? If you mean writing directly to the Window management system (e.g. Win32 or XORG) Versus using something like GLFW to create the window and rendering context, I'll be using GLFW with GLEW.

Comment: Wait, I think I get what you mean; I'd like to discover it in code using something like preprocessor directives or any OpenGL/related functions so I can call what I need to dynamically. For example, `#ifdef OPENGL_3_1
/* code for OpenGL 3.1 only */
#else
/* code for OpenGL > 3.1 */`

Comment: @about: I believe similar preprocessor things exist, such as #version __VERION__, where __VERSION__ gets replaced by the supported version of the GPU. But [this](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/171356-version-acrobatics) seems to say otherwise. Edit: two underscores get replaced by bold markup, but what i meant to say was --Version--, where - is a _.

Comment: You can't detect OpenGL version using the preprocessor. It runs during compilation and doesn't have any idea on what GPU will your program ever be run

Comment: @Kos Sorry, I meant to specify for GLSL. Does that also hold true for GLSL?

Comment: I don't really understand this question; GLSL doesn't have a preprocessor and is compiled by GPU

Comment: @Kos: "3.3 Preprocessor
There is a preprocessor that processes the source strings as part of the compilation process" From the [spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.20.11.clean.pdf).

Comment: No problem. Also, I found glGetString [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/). It's not preprocessor, but i guess you could create a dummy context to use these calls, and make a decision based on the versions returned by GL_VERSION, etc for OpenGL detection.